# Securing a Web Method

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, security

Say I've got a method in c# MVC to send email with ajax, like:

```
public class mailController : Controller {

        SmtpClient mailserver = new SmtpClient("smtp.foo.com");

        public string send(string from, string to, string subject = "", string body = "", string cc = "", string bcc = "") {
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, body);
            if (cc.Length > 0) {
                message.CC.Add(cc);
            }
            if (bcc.Length > 0) {
                message.Bcc.Add(bcc);
            }
            mailserver.Send(message);
            return "MessageSent";
        }
    }
```

Is there anything I can do to make this more secure? I mean, as it stands *anyone* can type the relevant info into their address bar. `http://www.foo.com/mail/send?from=etc` If I want to use this for form submission, I can't password protect it, or I'd have to use that in the javascript, which is easy to find. I considered setting a cookie and using that as authentication, but that only goes so far. **Is there a standard procedure for protecting ajax methods?**

Comment: Does your website already have security on it? If not, I'm not sure what you think can possibly be done here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to validate **on the server** that the parameters are what you want them to be.

Comment: It seems like this may be the best option I've got. At the very least, greatly limiting the scope of what my ajax methods can do will help, right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a secure session token, to prevent unauthorized users (those without valid sessions) from being able to send an email.  This is basically no different than any other cross site request forgery (CSRF) attack vector.  If you need any additional information just Google 'CSRF protection ASP.NET`' or similar to get some more concrete examples of how to do this.

Comment: I had considered a system like this, but this makes more sense if it's something that can only be called once a user is logged in. I think I already know the answer, but can this technique be used for security even if the user may be anonymous?

Comment: @Llepwryd Yes a session need not have any login tied to it.  Use of session-stored token is pretty much a basic practice for any form component to an application, regardless of login state.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements sound mutually exclusive.

If you do want to leave it public, but you don't want it abused, then maybe you could provide some sort of throttle where you only allow x number of requests from a specific IP address.

You can also use mailto: in an HTMLform to prompt the client to send the email.

Comment: Maybe security isn't the right word. It needs to be openly accessible, but not abusable (or at least minimally abusable).

Comment: Tricky, you need to just raise the bar high enough where it's not worth someone's effort to "abuse" it - but keep it simple for legitimate users. Perhaps a Captcha to check it's a human?

Answer (score 0):

As a start you can always store the IP that accessed your controller, if same IP is trying to send mail in specific frequency that you define you can deside to block it ot whatever...
at second you can generate a random number in your mailing page that will be send to the controller -> this will allow you to verify that the mail is sent from your site and not from third party